# Which are stronger intermolecular forces: ionic bonds or hydrogen bonds?

Tags: ions, hydrogen-bond

Do strong ionically attracted molecules have stronger intermolecular forces than hydrogen bonding forces?

Comment: Have a look at @chemistry department/Elmhurst College/hydrogen bonding. The hydrogen bond is usually considered stronger than normal dipole forces between molecules. The normal hydrogen bond is about 1/10 as strong as a normal covelant bond.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by ionic bonding! If it is Coulomb interaction between monopoles, it is far stronger than H bonding

Comment: Question is about ionic interactions between charged molecules, like tetramethylamonium acetate imo. @anna Could you confirm it?

Comment: a molecule is "An electrically neutral entity..." http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html

Comment: @DavePhD Then betaine may be better example.

Comment: @Mithoron I think the question is unclear as to whether it is asking about a force between separate ions (ionic bonding) or between charged portions of molecules, as in intermolecular salt bridges.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_bridge_(protein_and_supramolecular)

Comment: Yes, looks unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen bonds are the strongest intermolecular forces. Stronger than van der Waals' forces, namely (ordained by strength):

- Permanent dipole - permanent dipole (Keesom's Force);
- Permanent dipole - induced dipole (Debye force);
- induced dipole - induced dipole (London's dispersion force);

Strong hydrogen bonds are created by the FONs (fluorine, Oxygen and Nitrogen), which are very electronegatives, what produces a strong attraction between one them and hydrogen (which is less electronegative). As example of this interaction we can cite the water, that's a polar molecule in a "V" shape, take a look at the figure below.

Then, the both hydrogens yields a $\delta^{+}$ that's attracted by the Oxygen (very strong electronegative, the $\delta^{-}$ side) of the another water molecule, yielding the hydrogen bonds, take a look at the figure below.

[image: hydrogen bonds in water.]

Comment: Hydrogen bonding , an interaction involving a hydrogen atom located between a pair of other atoms having a high affinity for electrons. Such a bond is weaker than an ionic bond or covelant bond but stronger than van der Waals forces.(Ref:@Brittanica/hydrogen bonding). Ionic bond and van der Waals forces are both similar regarding electrostatic attraction but are describing different things specifically.

Comment: Won't lie... I thought your oversized water diagram was going to be a picture of a [Voltorb](https://images.rapgenius.com/bah9yycs0l9bm8flncotg5jqa.368x369x1.gif). In all seriousness though, you might consider removing it, since the more reasonably sized picture below also seems to demonstrate what you were talking about, or at least try resizing it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ringo! I'll try to resize this! :)

Comment: I edited your answer to remove some errors you can revet some of the changes if you disagree. vdW doesn't mean ionic - question is about ionic interactions between charged molecules, like tetramethylamonium acetate also @Greg