# Are hydrogen bonds stronger than ionic bonds?

Tags: hydrogen-bond

What is the order of strongest bonds to weakest? Are hydrogen bonds stronger than ionic bonds? Are hydrogen bonds covalent bonds?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41472/which-are-stronger-intermolecular-forces-ionic-bonds-or-hydrogen-bonds

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-why-cant-it-exist-with-atoms-other-than-f

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen bonding is very weak, it follows that order of forces:

Ionic bond > Covalent bond > Hydrogen bond > Van der Waals forces. (I have not included electrostatic force for sake of simplicity).

Hydrogen bonds can vary in strength from very weak ($1–2~\mathrm{kJ/mol}$) to extremely strong ($161.5~\mathrm{kJ/mol}$ in the ion $\ce{HF2−}$).
Typical enthalpies in vapor include:
\begin{array}{cl}
\ce{F−H\bond{...}:\!F}& \text{161.5 kJ/mol or 38.6 kcal/mol}\\
\ce{O−H\bond{...}:\!N}& \text{29 kJ/mol or 6.9 kcal/mol}\\
\ce{O−H\bond{...}:\!O}& \text{21 kJ/mol or 5.0 kcal/mol}\\
\ce{N−H\bond{...}:\!N}& \text{13 kJ/mol or 3.1 kcal/mol}\\
\ce{N−H\bond{...}:\!O}& \text{8 kJ/mol or 1.9 kcal/mol}\\
\ce{HO−H\bond{...}:\!OH3+}& \text{18 kJ/mol[15] or 4.3 kcal/mol}\\
\end{array}

{source-[Wikipedia](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjF_Nnp3LnQAhXMrY8KHWJhC_gQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHydrogen_bond&usg=AFQjCNHizh1SdkYnhAWhOZJXBDKDBbiCUw)}

Comment: Please also insert a link to the Wikipedia source pages.